# nestjs/graphql http://localhost:8083/graphql url keep running in 2 second interval

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Recently started to use nestjs/graphql, and trying to add middleware for all **/graphql** routes. And stuck with one question which is URL ***http://localhost:8083/graphql*** ,keep call with post request type in 2 seconds intervals as shown in the attached [snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSFxh.png).

Through R&D, I have found that [sample](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/23-graphql-code-first) in official github, the URL on application running is ***http://[::1]:3000*** and in network, API calls only when query runs(on button click).

so, the query is am I getting this wrong or right and, if it is right then which one is the right way.

Comment: Are you using GraphQL Playground? It seems so looking at the picture.
Playground polls the schema by default every 2 seconds, you can disable it in the Playground settings (the top right cog icon), the settings key is `schema.polling.enable`

Comment: THANKYOU @Ghero , i get it now thankyou